# Problema con funcion

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy creando un blog y se ha creado la siguiente función para tomar los tópicos del blog:

```
function getPostTopic($post_id) {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE id=
            (SELECT topic_id FROM post_topic WHERE post_id=$post_id) LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $topic = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $topic;
}
```

La cual me da un error:

> ***Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
>   C:\wamp\www\includes\public_functions.php on line 30***

Comment: Agrega un var_dump($result) despues que le asignas mysqli_query y mira ver que llega

Comment: O revisa $conn no vaya ser que te falte algun require o include

Comment: A simple vista, debes trasladar el paréntesis de cierre al final, así: `SELECT * FROM topics WHERE id=
        (SELECT topic_id FROM post_topic WHERE post_id=$post_id LIMIT 1)`, si no funciona, controla la consulta e imprime un mensaje de error para ver lo que pasa.

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas Me reporta boolean FALSE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si vas a usar una sub-consulta como criterio debes asegurar que ésta devuelve una sola fila/columna.

Para ello, debes trasladar el paréntesis al final:

```
function getPostTopic($post_id){
    global $conn;
    /*¿La conexión es válida?*/
    if($conn){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE id=
               (SELECT topic_id FROM post_topic WHERE post_id=$post_id LIMIT 1)";
        /*¿Es correcta la consulta?*/
        if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
            $topic = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        }else{
            $topic="Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }else{
        $topic="Error en la conexión: ";
    }
    /*Prueba*/
    var_dump($topic);
    return $topic;
}
```

El `LIMIT 1` es el que indica **a la sub-consulta** que debe devolver una sola fila. Si cierras el paréntesis antes, estarías indicando el límite a toda la consulta, y tendrás este error:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: gracias amigo, pero me sigue devolviendo el mismo error. seguire averiguando ;)

Comment: ¿Qué error devuelve?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in

Comment: Captura un mensaje de error para ver a qué se debe. Ahora te pongo un ejemplo.

Comment: @ricardoleivasikic he escrito un código controlado. Ahí debería decirte cuál es el error en sí. Pruébalo.

Comment: por este mismo hilo?

Comment: Sí @ricardoleivasikic he actualizado el código, si observas, tiene varios `if` para ir controlando las diferentes etapas del mismo.

Comment: vale amigo mio me envio el error, creo que no he podido crear de buena manera la una relacion en sql

Comment: string 'Error en la consulta: Table 'blog.post_topic' doesn't exist' (length=59)

Comment: AMIGO!!, solucionado, el problema surgio por un tema de que estaba mal escrito post_topic => post_topics era.. lo que no logro entender (estoy aprendiendo php entre un libro y tutoriales de blog) es porque anteriormente con el codigo hecho me mostro un error. he actualizado la version de php de wamp para que corra de mejor manera el codigo ya que el tutorial que sigo esta escrito para 7.0 y mi wamp tenia la 5.4.0